# facebook app: alternative way of getting userid (other than php-sdk)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

because of some bug, facebook php-sdk's getuser always return 0. [Why is Facebook PHP SDK getUser always returning 0?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6790272/why-is-facebook-php-sdk-getuser-always-returning-0)

How else can I get userId of the user currently using the application?

Answer (score 0):

Access `https://graph.facebook.com/me` with a valid access token and it'll return the current user's details as JSON.

Comment: can you please help me **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740168/facing-issue-while-trying-to-send-the-reply-to-facebook-post-in-mvc3)** ?